# Why is NHibernate doing an UPDATE rather than an INSERT?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Continuing my explorations in NHibernate with my podcast application, I've come across something odd: NHibernate is UPDATEing when I would expect an INSERT.  The situation is a simple one-to-many relationship between a podcast and its items.  Here's my NHibernate mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping assembly="App.DataModel">
  <class name="Feed" table="Feeds">
    <!-- snip -->
    <bag name="FeedItems" table="FeedItems" cascade="all">
      <key column="FeedId" />
      <one-to-many class="FeedItem" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The situation is: I've created a new `Podcast` object, updated it from the feed (so the Podcast.`FeedItems` collection property contains a number of `FeedItem`s) and am now saving it to the database via `ISession.Save()`.  Judging by the NHibernate log file, the `Podcast` object is correctly inserted into the database, but the `FeedItems` collection is being UPDATEd instead.  Here's the SQL generated for the `Podcast`:

```
INSERT INTO Feeds (
    Uri, IsPublic, Title, Description, Link, Language, Copyright, 
    LastBuildDate, PublishDate, Docs, Webmaster, Author, Subtitle, 
    Summary, OwnerName, OwnerEmail, IsExplicit, ImageUri, Id 
) VALUES (
    @p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, 
    @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18
);
```

And here's the SQL generated for the `FeedItem`s:

```
UPDATE FeedItems SET PublishDate = @p0, Author = @p1, 
    IsExplicit = @p2, Subtitle = @p3, Summary = @p4, 
    Duration = @p5 WHERE Id = @p6;
```

I don't get why an UPDATE is happening when the `FeedItem`s don't necessarily even exist yet.  I'm chasing this down, because the test that exercises this code is failing with the exception

`NHibernate.StaleStateException: Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1`

**Update with more logging**: Following some more tweaks, I spotted the following line in the NHibernate log:

`Collection found: [Podcast.FeedItems#GUID], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to this issue was the exception message

`NHibernate.StaleStateException: Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1`

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070311/how-to-save-a-child-with-assigned-id-in-nhibernate) I realised that my IDs were being assigned by my own code and not by NHibernate, which caused NHibernate to think that the entities had already been saved.  Once I removed the code auto-generating new IDs, the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen when the `unsaved-value` attribute on my  element didn't match up against the corresponding property value for a new entity.  Here's an example:

```
<class name="Foo">
  <id name="ID" unsaved-value="-1" type="Int32">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
</class>
```

and

```
public class Foo 
{
  private int _id = 0;
  public int ID {
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id = value; }
  }
}
```

In this case, saving a new Foo will result in NHib generating an UPDATE since it thinks that the object already has an identity.

Comment: Does this only apply to IDs?  I'm using GUIDs for IDs, but all my mappings include an unsaved-value attribute specifying the zero GUID on the <id /> element.

Comment: I would tend to use a `System.Guid?` (`Nullable<System.Guid>`), and have `null` be the `unsaved-value`.

Comment: Doesn't the non-null requirement on ids prevent this?