# SharpArch.Core.PreconditionException: For better clarity and reliability, Entities with an assigned Id must call Save or Update

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

When I do a save of an entity with assigned id I get a

> SharpArch.Core.PreconditionException:
>   For better clarity and reliability,
>   Entities with an assigned Id must call
>   Save or Update

My class is

```
public class CompanyUserRepository :
RepositoryWithTypedId<CompanyUser, string>, ICompanyUserRepository
{
   public override CompanyUser SaveOrUpdate(CompanyUser entity)
   {
     var user = base.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
     //Do some stuff
     return user;
   }
}
```

How do I go about saving this entity?

`RepositoryWithTypedId` does not expose a Save method

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070311/how-to-save-a-child-with-assigned-id-in-nhibernate). This tells you the reason, but I haven't found out the Sharp Architecture way to do a `Save`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging through the NorthWind example in the S#arp repo, I found out the answer.

The Repository class should derive from `NHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId`

e.g.

```
public class CustomerRepository : NHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId<Customer, string>, ICustomerRepository
{
    public List<Customer> FindByCountry(string countryName) {
        ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Customer))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("Country", countryName));


        return criteria.List<Customer>() as List<Customer>;
    }
}
```