# NHibernate force Guid generation at collection insert

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I want to add a new Entity in my Aggregate Root. This works fine, but does not force an Id generation.

To make it more clear take following example code, where all Entities are mapped with `Id(e => e.Uid).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();`.

```
public class Aggregate : EntityBase<Guid,Aggregate>
{
   // ...
   public virtual ISet<SubEntity> SubEntities { get; protected set; }

   public virtual SubEntity DoSomethingThatCreatesASubEntity(string name, string format)
   {
       var newEntity=new SubEntity(name, format);
       SubEntities.Add(newEntity);
       return newEntity;
   }
}
public class SubEntity : EntityBase<Guid,SubEntity>
{
}
// Client Code:
var agr=Session.Get<Aggregate>(id);
var subEntity=agr.DoSomethingThatCreatesASubEntity("xyz","xyz");
Assert.True(subEntity.IsTransient);
Session.Flush();
Assert.False(subEntity.IsTransient);
```

What I want is that when i add to the SubEntites that newEntity will be reloaded with the Uid. 
I do not want to access the NHibernate ISession there (so Session.Save() or Refresh()) are out of reach.

Is this possible without modifying my Entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two options:

1. Assign the id manually before saving. In this case, NHibernate will not be able to detect that it is a new entity unless you add a `Version` or `Timestamp` column. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070311/how-to-save-a-child-with-assigned-id-in-nhibernate).
2. Return the `SubEntity` itself from your method (after all, in DDD, why do you want to pass around GUIDs?) Anything holding a reference to that sub-entity will get the latest id once the aggregate root is saved at the end of your session. Presumably, the session will be flushed before control passes back to the front-end code, which is where the id will be needed, but calling code needs to be aware that extracting ids midway through a session is a bad idea.

Comment: You´re right about not passing Guid´s (I´m using a domain event to drive a transactional resource...). I just had to keep the reference to "newEntity" until the session is flushed. After that the Uid is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate ids manually (set id generator to assign) then every time you create a new entity you should set its id and you will have this id available in your application without using ISession.Later you can use ISession to save this object into database.The only problem with this approach is NHibernate won't have a clue which object is created and which object is updated (you can't use SaveOrUpdate method of session) you should either use Save and Update methods explicitly or you can insert an interceptor that use a logic to see if an object is updated or inserted and then you can use SaveOrUpdate again.