# Unable to determine if entity is transient or detached

Tags: .net, nhibernate, transient

I am getting a weird error in NHibernate (v3.3), when trying to persist an entity with a manually generated ID:

> Unable to determine if {Entity} with assigned identifier {Id} is transient or detached; querying the database. 
>     Use explicit Save() or Update() in session to prevent this.

But the problem is, I *am* using `Save` instead of `SaveOrUpdate`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have any abstraction layer sitting over NHibernate? Do you have any version/timestamp columns? Can you post your mappings & code?

Comment: At the end I realized the problem was with cascading child entities when saving the parent one, there is an answer on SO which explains possible ways to fix that. I already fixed it but haven't had time to post my findings.

Comment: woud you mind linking the answer which solved your problem?

Comment: @Firo: sure, as I mentioned, I was rather busy, I'll do it in a moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out that my problem was actually happening while saving the parent entity, containing child entities in a one-to-many relation:

```
<class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="ParentTable" table="ParentTable">

    <id name="ManuallyAssignedId">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <!- child table also has a manually assigned id -->
    <bag cascade="all" inverse="true" name="ChildTable">
      <key>
        <column name="ParentTable_id"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="ChildTable" />
    </bag>

</class>
```

In other words, a call to `Save` on the parent entity caused a `SaveOrUpdate` on child entities, which NHibernate was complaining about.

When I realized that, I quickly found this StackOverflow thread: [How to save a child with assigned id in nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1070311/1488067), which has two great suggestions:

1. [Create and map a Version or Timestamp column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070475/1488067) - if it's null, NHibernate will know it needs to persist the entity, or
2. [Attach a custom Interceptor to a session (or session factory)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1075232/1488067) and use a custom private field to keep track of whether the entity needs to be persisted.