# NHibernate.Engine.ForeignKeys - Unable to determine if entity is transient or detached

Tags: nhibernate

I have this **Instrument** entity:

```
<class name="Instrument" table="Instruments" mutable="false">
    <id name="ID" column="INSTRUMENT_ID" unsaved-value="0">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="....." />
    <property name="....." />
</class>
```

This entity is used in many-to-one relationship in other entity (**InstrumentSelection**). This is many-to-one mapping info:

```
<many-to-one name="Instrument" access="field.camelcase" column="Instrument_ID" update="false" class="Instrument" not-null="true" fetch="join" lazy="false" />
```

The issue I've it that when I save **InstrumentSelection** entity with **Save**:

```
Transact(() => session.Save(entity));
```

I get error in logs:

> 2012-12-20 14:09:54,607 WARN 12 NHibernate.Engine.ForeignKeys - Unable
>   to determine if Instrument with assigned
>   identifier 11457 is transient or detached; querying the database. Use
>   explicit Save() or Update() in session to prevent this.

**A few facts about Instrument entity:**

- It's just a reference entity
- It's immutable entity
- It can not be added / inserted via application. I get rows in database from external feed.

**Question (version 1)**: A my question is: is there a way to instruct NHibernate to always consider Instrument entity as detached? I mean - if an instance of Instrument exists in application it means that it's present in database. So there is no too much sense in quering the database.

#### EDIT 1: Because **Question (version 1)** was not answered yet, let me change it slightly:

**Question (version 2)**: What could be the behaviour that NHibernate is still trying to work out whether entity is detached/transient? I think I have my mapping configured correctly (**unsaved-value**, **generator**).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you save the InstrumentSelection, NHibernate is cascading the operation to save the child Instruments. My first suggestion is to set cascade to none on the InstrumentSelect side of the relationship.

My second suggestion is to use an interceptor as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1075232/12752).

Comment: I've already created a workaround with interceptor (exactly the same solution) - works fine. Also I've tried cascade option - in vain. I still was facing the issue. Anyway, perhaps I'll rephrase my question. Please see updated question.